# Unequally spaced columns in XYpic

Tags: xy-pic

I often need to create a diagram in XYpic where the distance between the columns varies. This is usually when one has a map to some object X where the definition of X is in the diagram itself, like

```
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r] & B = \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}
    \\
    a \ar@{|->}[r] & b
}
\end{equation*}
```

If you actually typeset this, the lower b will be aligned to the center of the rather large second column, while one wants it below the upper B. A solution is to write

```
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r] & B & = \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}
    \\
    a \ar@{|->}[r] & b
}
\end{equation*}
```

so that the definition of B is in the third column. The problem is now that the equal sign is too far from the B to which it refers.

Such a thing is easy to do in kuvio, but kuvio does not support pdflatex, and moreover my coworkers have chosen xypic instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xypic,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{
    A \ar[r] & \mathrlap{B = \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}}
    \\
    a \ar@{|->}[r] & b
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is definitely the best solution. Still it is not perfect since the long entry now has 0 width, which may not be good for the layout. It is still disappointing that XYpic does not allow to move columns.

Comment: I withdraw my previous comment: of course only part of the column may be put inside mathrlap. This is definitely THE solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andrea: you can add a ` & \rule{2cm}{0pt} ` after the rlap line, then it will be shifted to the left

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the excursion command described on page 9 of xyguide.pdf:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix{
    A \ar[r] & B &
      \save[]+<1.75em,0em>*{= \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}}\restore  \\
    a \ar@{|->}[r] & b
  }
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `tikz-cd`. With help of the package `calc` you are able to set the width of both cell to the same value:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar{r} & \mathmakebox[\widthof{$b$}][l]{B = \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}}\\
    a \ar[mapsto]{r}& b
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the desired spacing by adapting your proposed solution. I just made the column width negligible and added in an extra column. I don't know if there is a better way of accomplishing the desired result.

```
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix@C=-2pt{
    A \ar[rr] &\qquad& B &= \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}
    \\
    a \ar@{|->}[rr]& & b
}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Uhm... thank you, but if this is the only solution I may just use aligned equations and manually adjust horizontal position by adding spaces. I was hoping XYpic could do better... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another example, it uses only xypic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@!0@=15mm{
A \ar[r] &**[r] B = \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}\\
a \ar@{|->}[r] & b
}
\]
\end{document}
```

The @!0 forces all distances between rows and columns to be zero so they don't automatically change. Then @=15mm sets the distances of rows and columns exactly at 15mm, and the solution to your question is to write **[r] which tells xymatrix to move that particular entry to the right, you could also use **[l] to move it to the left.

[image]

I would actually go further and bring the rows closer using @R=5mm and @C=15mm to specify the distances of the rows and columns separately.

```
\[
\xymatrix@!0@C=15mm@R=5mm{
A \ar[r] &**[r] B = \{c \in C \mid f(c) = 0 \}\\
a \ar@{|->}[r] & b
}
\]
```

[image]